# как проверить на отрицательное число

Tags: javascript

Помогите пожалуйста, как на JavaScript проверить отрицательное число. При введение отрицательного число проверить в условии при строгом равенстве.

Вот мой код:

```js
var getNumber = function(intNumber) {
  var number = parseInt(intNumber);
  if (number === null) {
    console.log("Вы нажали \"Отмена\"");
  } else if (number === -10) {
    console.log("Вы ввели отрицательное число");
  } else if (number == false) {
    console.log("Вы ввели ноль");
  } else if (isNaN(number)) {
    console.log("Вы ввели не число");
  } else {
    console.log("Вы ввели положительное число");
  }

  return number;
};

var numberFree = getNumber(prompt("Введите число: "));
```

Comment: Ну даже не знаю ... `number < 0`

Comment: в данном случае number никогда не будет равен null или false, хотя да, нестрогое сравнение с false сработает

Comment: 'number === null' по идее хотел использовать если пользователь нажал отмена при запросе prompt.

Comment: @Чингиз, тогда эту проверку надо делать **ДО** вызова `parseInt`

Comment: @Grundy Получилось, 'var getNumber = function (intNumber) {
           var number = parseInt(intNumber);
           if (intNumber === null) {
             alert("Вы нажали \"Отмена\"");
           }'

вот так сделал. Спасибо.

Comment: да. в принципе можно и так. Обычно просто сначала делают проверку, и лишь затем выполняют `parse`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Отрицательное число – это число, которое меньше 0.

В яваскрипт есть оператор сравнения: [оператор меньше (`<`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B_%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F#%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B5(%3C)).

Для проверки, что число меньше 0, запись будет выглядеть так:

```
number < 0
```

Comment: Спасибо, буду знать

Comment: @Grundy, `(-0.2 < 0) === true // true`  `(Math.round(-0.2) < 0) === true // false` [Math.sign](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/sign#Polyfill)

Comment: @Grundy, что интересно, это `x => x!=0 && !(x>0)` тоже не верное, так как `+0>0 //false`

Answer (score 1):

Можно проверить еще так, как вариант:

```js
//для всех отрицательных чисел метод возвращает -1
console.log(Math.sign(-5));
```